# Wordpress+WooCommerce: Get Attributes outside of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get WooCommerce product attributes outside of Wordpress.

I already have **loaded the wp-load.php** file to get some WP values.
After that, I use the function "**get_attribute" to load the value "pa_eyes"**.
Inside of the WordPress-template it works.. outside of Wordpress it doesn't work.

I know: the code want to get the ID of the product, which is f.e. "2019". How can I send this ID to the function?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

 define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
 require( '/is/htdocs/x/www/x/web/wp-load.php' );

 global $product;
 echo $product->get_attribute('pa_eyes');

?>
```

I hope and think you can help me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: remove the `global $product;` line and replace it with:
`$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();  
$product = $_pf->get_product(2019);` it should work

Comment: Thank you!

Also I had to remove the SHORTINIT-Line. Here is the answer:

`<?php

 require( '/is/htdocs/x/www/x/web/wp-load.php' );
$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
$product = $_pf->get_product(2019);
echo $product->get_attribute('pa_eyes');

?>`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've seen, that the functions `get_product` and `get_attribute` are deprecated.

Does it give a better solution with long term support?

Thanks!